# How to deactivate Code Editor option on Gutenberg editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have been trying to deactivate the "Code editor" on the Gutenberg editor, but I haven't found any resource to achieve that.

All I haven't seen so far is how to disable the Gutenberg editor (there are even plugins to do that).

[image]

This was the [closest approach](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-disable-code-editor-for-non-admin-users/) I found but it didn't work.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Kind regards.

Comment: Could you post the body classes of when a admin is logged in and the body classes of user or non admin that is logged in?

Comment: Sure. 

Admin: `wp-admin wp-core-ui js acf-admin-5-3 acf-browser-chrome index-php auto-fold admin-bar branch-5-9 version-5-9-3 admin-color-fresh locale-en-us customize-support svg`.

Normal user: `wp-admin wp-core-ui js acf-admin-5-3 acf-browser-chrome profile-php auto-fold admin-bar branch-5-9 version-5-9-3 admin-color-fresh locale-en-us mobile no-customize-support sticky-menu svg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code. You have to insert it into the functions.php of your child theme.

```
add_action('admin_head', 'orders_list_preview_css');
function orders_list_preview_css() {

    
echo "<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   setTimeout(function() {
     $('.components-button').on('click', function () {
       setTimeout(function() {
       $('.profile-php .components-menu-item__item:contains(\"Code editor\")').closest('button').remove();},100)
       })
    },500)
})
</script>";}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Removing `.profile-php` does the trick. Do you see that class on the article editor's page?